# Were Nixie tubes used by a space program?

Tags: nasa, history, technology

I’ve been receiving this ad from a company selling Nixie tube clock kits online:
[image: A Nixie clock with a fake plant]

> The technology that was used in the first space shuttles and submarines can be in your home and moreover in a unique design. ✈️ We are talking about original digitrons from 1976.
> Assemble a limited design piece! ‍♂️

I don’t recall seeing Nixie tubes (aka Digitron, Inditron, Numicator) used anywhere in the Space Shuttle. They were in the lunar shuttle scene in Kubrick’s *2001: A Space Odyssey*, but that is unfortunately a work of fiction and not an answer to this question.

(How) were Nixie tubes ever used by any space program?

Comment: I removed the Shuttle tag, as your question is clearly not limited to that program.

Comment: @DrSheldon thanks, I changed the question to be more broad as I wrote it & forgot to go back and edit tags

Comment: No Nixies in the shuttles. They had some 8 segment LED displays.

Comment: No Nixies in the first submarines. They long pre-dated electronics.

Comment: I’m beginning to think this ad might not be entirely truthful!

Comment: No idea if it ever flew, but this website has an image of one of these "soviet space clocks" with Nixie tubes: http://www.leapsecond.com/pages/space-clock/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [*Apollo Experience Report: Crew Station Displays and Controls*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19750012347), NASA Tech Note D-7919, the only Nixie intended for use in Apollo was cancelled:

> The first change involved the nucleonics quantity measuring system developed for the service module and LM reaction control system. This gaging system consisted of many small radioactive sources placed externally on one side of an RCS tank and a scintillator-photomultiplier counter placed on the other side. The idea was that the propellant would scatter or absorb radiation at a rate proportional to the quantity remaining in the tank . This quantity would then be displayed on a digital readout. **A Nixie tube display was baselined for the CM -- the only spacecraft application of such
> a display**. Unfortunately , problems were encountered in the development program; the cost increased, and **the system was canceled**.
>
> p. 22

Electroluminescent displays were preferred, including the 7-segment displays used for the DSKY.

Comment: Since you've mentioned an early digital nuclear particle counter, the technology for counting particles in the earliest days was [dekatron tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekatron) which are a little bit like nixie tubes in that they were cold cathode displays and had the same neon color, but they used the discharge tubes themselves as the counters, the plasma would jump from one number to the next each time a pulse was received from the previous tube, and the 9-to-0 transition would send a pulse to the next tube.

Comment: [1](http://madrona.ca/e/edte/Paratime130/index.html), [2](http://www.959radio.co.uk/dekatron.html), [3](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/restored-nucleus-k2-decade-dekatron-1859600130), [4](http://www.sgitheach.org.uk/atomic.html), [5](https://twitter.com/sfrolov/status/1066629653060816897), [6](https://alexwlchan.net/2017/11/five-years-of-witch/)

Answer (score 6):

Nixie tubes were used for [real time clocks (e.g. mission elapsed time) in mission control](https://www.ebay.com/itm/224370868004) during the Apollo era. I don't think they were used in spacecraft.

Comment: Yeah, they look somewhat large, heavy, and brittle compared to a mechanical solution.

Comment: It's plausible (but I have no evidence) that they were also used in ground support equipment.  But definitely not in the spacecraft, as per my answer.

Comment: @Jörg Nixies were awesome, but they did have a reputation of being a little more likely to develop faults than typical vacuum tubes of that size.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> MCC (in 1960-1973), from where the Soviet spacecraft were controlled. This photo shows a fragment of the hall with a number of operators' workplaces along the wall, a computer terminal for the Minsk-22 computer) and on the wall a large digital display (those same Nixie-indicators, as they say now) with the parameters of the spacecraft. The photo was taken after the end of the work. Therefore, everything is turned off in the photo and only a television employee at his remote control is in the frame (a microphone, a video monitor are visible). This is the only known photo of the "flight control room".